# Should I enable VT-x on VirtualBox? (32 bit OS)

Tags: virtualbox, vt-x

AFAIK for 32 bit OS, VT-x isnt needed.

Besides using 64 bit OS, when should I use VT-x?

Comment: Generally, for any VM.  You'll get the benefits of the hardware virtualization, so you should see better performance.

Comment: You definitely want VT-x enabled.